# Adaptive cards suggestedActions on Teams app Android not showing dislike emoji - UTF-8 code String.fromCodePoint(0x1F44E);

Tags: adaptive-cards, teams-toolkit

Teams application - is not showing dislike button (suggested actions) on Teams Android application. Like button is showing as expected but dislike button is empty. Tried changing place of dislike button, tried directly with pasting utf-8 code, tried with code point.

Example of code can be found here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-formatting-cards/nodejs

In Web Teams application it's working as expected

```
async sendAdaptiveCardFormats(turnContext) {

    let thumbsUp = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F44D);
    // Directly including the Unicode character
    let thumbsUPDirectly = '';

    let thumbsDown = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F44E);
    // Directly including the Unicode character
    let thumbsDownDirectly = '';


    let utfTest = String.fromCodePoint(0x1f615);


    const cardActions = [
        {
            type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
            title: 'Test adaptive card',
            value: 'PersonaSet'
        },
        {
            type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
            title: thumbsDown,
            value: 'HTMLConnector'
        },
        {
            type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
            title: thumbsUp,
            value: 'CardWithEmoji'
        }
    ];


    var reply = MessageFactory.attachment(this.sendLoreIpsumCard());

    reply.suggestedActions = { "actions": cardActions, "to": [turnContext.activity.from.id] };

    await turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
}
```

In Teams web dislike button is working:
[image]

In Teams Mobile app ( Android) dislike button is not visible in suggested actions:
[image]

Comment: I have tested on Iphone it's the same. Thumbs down is not showing